# Table that lists the pages a item is used on

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using **JasperReports 3.7.6** with **JavaBeans**.

I have a report that has a tree hierarchy

I need to add a summary table at the end of the report listing the name of all the elements of the tree and the pages where the elements are used.

My problem is that I don't know *how to get*  **the page numbers for each element**.

I looked around on forums and I'm guessing I have to define a variable or something like that but I don't have much experience with Jasper and don't know where to start.

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
Name of person | pages used on  
John Smith     | 2,4,6  
Jane Doe       | 1,3
```

Comment: Have you got anything to show what you have tried?

Comment: show your efforts `your code`?

Comment: I don't have any code for getting the page numbers for each elements I do have the tree hierarchy part of the report but that wouldn't be of any help here. I said in the post that I don't even know where to start with the getting the page numbers. All I've been doing until now was trying to find a solution. I don't even want a full solution. Any hint would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem. It might not be the best one but it works. I have added a parameter that is a Java class that I created. It contains a list and a method that receives the id of  the field I need and the page number param from jasper. I use that to build my list. And then in Jasper report I have a label that is used only for calling the method in my bean. Then all I had to do was put the index table in the summary band and tell it to get the value from the list I built.In jasper :

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{indexData}.addByIndex($F{numberInList},$F{indexLabel},$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + "")]]></textFieldExpression>
```

In Java

```
public class ReportIndexDataAction {

private List<ReportIndexData> reportIndexDataList;

public ReportIndexDataAction() {
    reportIndexDataList = new ArrayList<ReportIndexData>();
}

public List<ReportIndexData> getReportIndexDataList() {
    return reportIndexDataList;
}

public void setReportIndexDataList(List<ReportIndexData> reportIndexDataList) {
    this.reportIndexDataList = reportIndexDataList;
}

public String addByIndex(int index, String name, String page) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (Iterator iterator = reportIndexDataList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        ReportIndexData type = (ReportIndexData) iterator.next();
        if(type.getIndex() == index) {
            if(!type.getUsages().contains(","+ page + ",")) {
                type.setUsages((type.getUsages().isEmpty() ? "," + page +"," : type.getUsages() + page + ","));
            }
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found) {
        ReportIndexData data = new ReportIndexData();
        data.setIndex(index);
        data.setName(name);
        data.setUsages(","+ page + ",");
        reportIndexDataList.add(data);
    }
    return "";
}
```

and

```
public class ReportIndexData {

private int index;
private String name;
private String usages;

public int getIndex() {
    return index;
}
public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getUsages() {
    return usages;
}
public void setUsages(String usages) {
    this.usages = usages;
}
```

}